# How to keep List name using Gson

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

I need to get JSON response

```
{
 "text": [
          "blabla",
          "blabla",
          "blabla"
 ]
}
```

I have list of Strings

```
List<String> text = new ArrayList<String>();
text.add("blabla");
text.add("blabla");
text.add("blabla");
```

How can I get wright result, because my solution seems to me not the best one?

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
String answ = gson.toJson(text);
return "{\"text\":"+answ+"}";
```

Comment: The JSON is an object, with one attribute named text, containing an array of strings. So map it to a Java object, with an attribute named text, containing a list of strings.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define `text` as key of a map or DTOs field name

Here is how you can do this using use Guava's ImmutableMap map

```
return gson.toJson(ImmutableMap.of("text", text));
```

Or

```
HashMap<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("text", text);
return gson.toJson(map);
```

Or

Define a DTO named Data

```
public class Data {

    private List<String> text;

    public List<String> getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(List<String> text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

}
```

Then use :

```
Data data = new Data();
data.setText(text);
return gson.toJson(data);
```